# Change UTC time output from API string, angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, utc

Im making a twitter bot that reads time for sunrise and sunset from an api and then posts the result to twitter. I want to add two hours to the output time for both sunrise and sunset to match my local time.

for example, my output now is 
"sunset: 8:10:09 PM
 sunrise: 1:01:19 AM"

and I want it to be 
"sunset: 10:10:09 PM
 sunrise: 3:01:19 AM"

Any thoughts on how to do this?

angularJs code:
**controller**

```
$http.get("https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json? 
lat=63.8258&lng=20.2630&date=today", {})
  .then(function(response){
    console.log("Sunrise: " + response.data.results.sunrise);
    console.log("Sunset: " + response.data.results.sunset);
    $scope.string = ("sunset: " + response.data.results.sunset + "\n" + 
"sunrise: " + response.data.results.sunrise);
  });

  $scope.post_tweet = function(){
    $http.post('index.php',{
      'string':$scope.string
    }).then(function(response){
      //clear the form fields
      $scope.msg = true;
      $timeout(function(){$scope.msg = false;}, 1000);
      console.log("in " + response.data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead getting formatted time. You can try getting not-formatted date

Ex:
    https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/jsonlat=36.7201600&lng=-4.4203400&formatted=0

Returns:

```
{"results":{"sunrise":"2018-05-23T05:04:11+00:00","sunset":"2018-05-23T19:24:45+00:00","solar_noon":"2018-05-23T12:14:28+00:00","day_length":51634,"civil_twilight_begin":"2018-05-23T04:34:44+00:00","civil_twilight_end":"2018-05-23T19:54:13+00:00","nautical_twilight_begin":"2018-05-23T03:58:23+00:00","nautical_twilight_end":"2018-05-23T20:30:33+00:00","astronomical_twilight_begin":"2018-05-23T03:18:34+00:00","astronomical_twilight_end":"2018-05-23T21:10:22+00:00"},"status":"OK"}
```

Then in your code if you try JSON date string to Date object. i.e. new Date(results.sunrise), this value returned by new Date will be in your local timezone.

Suggestion: I suggest you might want to use https://momentjs.com/ for date conversion/formatting.